# Error when register app on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, app, register

Need to register an app on Sharepoint
I got this form:
[image: Register form]

After fill it and click CREATE i get:

[image: Error message]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to click the generate button.

You could following this to register app:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with Redirect URI. I pasted there SharePoint page URL. I passed this when I changed it to www address to my company's homepage.